# SQL Server - Protect my stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, database, security, stored-procedures

I'm working with SQL Server on a database which has tables, views and stored procedures. This database will surely be used by some other persons and I want to block the access to my stored procedures code. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Who are the "other persons" you want to block?  What kind of privileges do they have on the sql server/database?

Comment: It is in a consultancy context. The stored procedures have some confidential data. They should have all the privileges on the server/db except reading/writing the stored procedures.

Comment: THen you are screwed. There is no real way to protect a SP From the DBA. In modern SQL Server you could try moving the SP into a .NET class and possibly make that non-compilable but ..... not really a supported approach

Comment: "The stored procedures have some confidential data".  What does that mean?  Is it data in a table that the sp accesses?  Tsql comments within the sp definition?

Answer (score 2):

You can encrypt procedure code (if that is what you want to hide) by adding "With Encryption":

```
Create Procedure MyProc
With Encryption 
As
    Select 1;
```

But for sysadmins its still will be possible to get to procedure code (with a bit of effort).

Comment: I'd rephrase that as "with a trivial amount of effort".  Or anyone who restores a backup of the database on their own SQL Server instance.  Note that backups aren't protected by SQL Server permissions once they're made.

Answer (score 1):

You can revoke their EXECUTE permission on your stored procedure something like this..

```
REVOKE EXECUTE ON OBJECT::dbo.Proc_Name
FROM NaughtyPerson;
GO
```